# Having issue with Email personalize with %%First Name%%

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email-template

I have created an email template on Salesforce Marketing Cloud and I want to add `%%FirstName%%` personalization string to it. However, I haven't been able to do so after trying different syntaxes. Below is my current syntax:

```
 %%[
IF Empty(@First Name) OR @First Name == "Unknown" THEN
 set @FirstName = "colleague and friend of NALRC"
ENDIF
]%%

Dear %%=v(@FirstName)=%%,
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: If you are using the above the code in your email template, then in your email use %%=v(@FirstName)=%%

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is with the space in the Data Extension column name. I try to avoid spaces in column names as it inevitably causes me problems somewhere.

In this case I used AttributeValue to retrieve the value from the row and UpperCased the Unknown just to be extra safe in case of casing issues.

```
%%[
var @FirstName

IF Empty(AttributeValue("First Name")) OR Uppercase(AttributeValue("First Name")) == "UNKNOWN" 
THEN 
SET @FirstName = "colleague and friend of NALRC"
ELSE
SET @FirstName = AttributeValue("First Name")
ENDIF

]%%

Dear %%=v(@FirstName)=%%
```

Comment: Hi Aaron, Thank you for the answer. I copied your code and pasted it, however still not showing up. How can I change field name as you suggested?

Comment: What is the Data Extension column name?

Comment: The column name is "First Name"

Comment: I created a DE in my environment with the "First Name" as a column and it worked with the above code. Are you getting an error or is it just not replacing with tthe Colleague value?

Comment: I don't get any error. It is just not replacing.

Comment: It just says "Dear ,", the "Colleague" value does not show up either

Comment: Does it show that for all records or only the empty or unknown values?

Comment: It shows it for all records

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is in this case. I would expect this to show the Colleague text at the very least if there was an incorrect column name. I can confirm this works with a "First Name" column of type text. Are you certain the code copied over correctly in it's entirety? Are you certain the personalization string is being called correctly for the variable that's being set: %%=v(@FirstName)=%%

Comment: I will continue with working on it. I will check if the column is text or not. As for copying text, I copied all of it and pasted it. I am certain that the personalization string is being called correctly. I appreciate your wonderful help.

Answer (score 0):

It could be good practice to use underscores instead of spaces in column names for your target audience. I hope the code below helps in some way.

```
%%[
VAR @FirstName
SET @FirstName = Trim(AttributeValue("First Name")) 

IF EMPTY(@FirstName) OR @FirstName == "Unknown" THEN
    SET @FirstName = "colleage and friend of NALRC"
ENDIF
]%%
Dear %%=v(@FirstName)=%%,
```